# Comparing two byte arrays guarding against timing attacks

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, jit, timing-attack

I want to write a method to compare two byte arrays, but I do not want to use [these](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43289/196844) [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/627742/196844) because I want the method to be resistant to timing attacks.  My method essentially looks like:

```
static bool AreEqual(byte[] a1, byte[] a2)
{
    bool result = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < a1.Length; ++i)
    {
        if (a1[i] != a2[i])
            result = false;
    }
    return result;
}
```

(with the assumption that `a1` and `a2` have the same length).

My concern is that a sufficiently smart just-in-time compiler might optimize this by returning early if `result` is ever set to false.

I [have checked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29868085/196844) the JITted assembly code produced by .NET 4.0.30319, and it does not:

```
                         ; `bool result = true;'
00e000d1 bb01000000      mov     ebx,1
                         ; `int i = 0;'
00e000d6 33f6            xor     esi,esi
                         ; store `a1.Length' in eax and at dword ptr [ebp-10h]
00e000d8 8b4104          mov     eax,dword ptr [ecx+4]
00e000db 8945f0          mov     dword ptr [ebp-10h],eax
                         ; if `a1.Length' is 0, then jump to `return result;'
00e000de 85c0            test    eax,eax
00e000e0 7e18            jle     00e000fa
                         ; `if (a1[i] != a2[i])'
00e000e2 0fb6443108      movzx   eax,byte ptr [ecx+esi+8]
00e000e7 3b7704          cmp     esi,dword ptr [edi+4]
00e000ea 7316            jae     00e00102
00e000ec 3a443708        cmp     al,byte ptr [edi+esi+8]
00e000f0 7402            je      00e000f4
                         ; `result = false;'
00e000f2 33db            xor     ebx,ebx
                         ; `++i'
00e000f4 46              inc     esi
                         ; check: `a1.Length > i'
00e000f5 3975f0          cmp     dword ptr [ebp-10h],esi
00e000f8 7fe8            jg      00e000e2
                         ; `return result;'
00e000fa 8bc3            mov     eax,ebx
00e000fc 59              pop     ecx
00e000fd 5b              pop     ebx
00e000fe 5e              pop     esi
00e000ff 5f              pop     edi
00e00100 5d              pop     ebp
00e00101 c3              ret
00e00102 e81f7a1772      call    clr!CreateHistoryReader+0x8e97c (72f77b26)
00e00107 cc              int     3
00e00108 0000            add     byte ptr [eax],al
00e0010a 0000            add     byte ptr [eax],al
00e0010c 0000            add     byte ptr [eax],al
00e0010e 0000            add     byte ptr [eax],al
...
```

However, I am thinking that this could change in the future.

Is there a way to prevent the JIT compiler from optimizing this method?  Alternatively, is there a library function that I can use that specifically checks two byte arrays for equality, but resistant to timing attacks?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16953231/cryptography-net-avoiding-timing-attack

Comment: @DarinDimitrov:  Thanks for your comment.  I had not seen that approach, but I was doing something similar where I was incrementing a counter for each difference and returning true if the counter was 0.  However, my approach and the approach which you have linked to could both be optimized by a sufficiently smart JIT compiler, right?

Comment: Suggestion: Replace `if (a1[i] != a2[i]) result = false;` with `result = result & (a1[i] == a2[i])`. That way, you don't even have a conditional, which could lead to different execution times depending on which branch is taken. (Disclaimer: I didn't check whether this actually makes a difference in the JITted code.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`MethodImplAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.methodimplattribute)-Class of the `System.Runtime.CompilerServices` namespace with the [`MethodImplOptions.NoOptimization`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.methodimploptions) option like this:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoOptimization)]
static bool AreEqual(byte[] a1, byte[] a2)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: A note that may be neccessary is that this only prevents the JIT compiler to optimize anything (thats what you have asked for). The IL code will still be optimized though if it was compiled with optimization options. But I think it will be unlikely that such an optimization you described will be present in future versions of the JIT and/or the compiler.