# How to make a simple "encrypted" password in an ASP.NET MVC application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I just want a single password that logs in to the admin part of my web app. So I don't think I need to create a table in the database just for this. I'm going to generate a random, safe password that I bake into the application. How can I do this in a secure way? Do I stick it in `web.config` or do I write it in the C# code like `private static readonly _pswd = ...` ?

Comment: Are you asking how to make a secure password, or where to store it?

Comment: You don't encrypt passwords, you hash them.

Comment: If I where you, I would store the hash of a password in the web.config so you could change it relatively easily every 90 days or something like that....

Comment: Never hardcode a password in your code

Comment: @StephenMuecke Then where does the hashing function get stored? And how is access to the hashing function any more secure than access to the hashed password? Doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: You hash it it with one of the cryptographic hash functions such as SHA256 (in `System.Security.Cryptography`). When the user submits the password, you run the same hashing function and compare it with your stored value.

Comment: @Gusman That is a rather strong statement. Perhaps we should never allow the key to be in memory either? Perhaps the executable file that contains the key is always encrypted at rest. Security needs to respond to the threat (attacker skill level, motivation, time willing to be invested and capabilities) and the value (of the object to the owner, reputation). Many tines these are sufficiently low such that the key will be available, not all applications require an HSM where the key is never available. It is about increasing the work factor to match the threat.

Comment: @SubparWebDev, [this article](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) might be of interest. Based on your question, you probably don't need to go as far as the article suggests, but it will give you a general understanding of best practice

Comment: If you have to ask why it's possible that someone gets access to the hashing algorithm and the hash and you're still not burned, then you don't understand enough about cryptography to be doing it. Before asking on Stack Overflow how to implement it, go learn some of the basics of cryptography, specifically the difference between encryption and a one way hash.

Comment: Honestly, at this point in time, [it's so rediculously easy to implement real authorization and authentication schemes](http://www.asp.net/identity) it may actually be harder not to.  Even if all you do is pass a password to a controller and hardcode a user, as soon as the requirements change you don't have to now rip apart code to implement a full featured user/pass system....

Comment: @zaph Hardcode your key, get bad luck and get hacked, you will regret to have hardcoded it when you need to recompile and redistribute your program to avoid attacks...

Comment: @Gusman The point is you said "Never ". It depends on what you are protecting, from whom and the value. If you use the encryption key it is vulnerable. To get access an iOS executable file you have to have a jailbroken device, and have the tools to examine the running executable, it can not be examined at rest, it is encrypted. At that point I will see your key while it is used. Give me a solution where I can't get your key. I am not saying it is a good idea but it depends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use PBKDF2 to store a salted hash of your password.  First, create a console application, and use it to calculate the hash, like this:

```
var r = new System.Security.Cryptography.Rfc2898DeriveBytes("password!", 16, 100000);
byte[] saltedHash = r.GetBytes(32);
byte[] salt = r.Salt;
```

Run this and use the debugger to look at the contents of `saltedHash` and `salt` (or write a few more lines of code to write them to a text file).  Then use that to write a method like this:

```
    private static Boolean passwordCorrect(string pw)
    {
        byte[] salt = { 0x2A, 0x6B, 0xE3, 0xAB, 0x21, 0x78, 0xC6, 0xEE, 0xC9, 0xF0, 0xDB, 0xC6, 0xFA, 0x7A, 0x4E, 0x98 };
        var r = new System.Security.Cryptography.Rfc2898DeriveBytes(pw, salt, 100000);
        var entered = r.GetBytes(32);
        byte[] pbkdf2 = { 0xAF, 0x16, 0x60, 0xA3, 0xD0, 0x58, 0x2C, 0xCF, 0xA2, 0x32, 0xE0, 0x3B, 0x18,
            0x75, 0xDD, 0x6F, 0xA3, 0x35, 0x8, 0x70, 0x6B, 0x72, 0x45, 0xEC, 0xD7, 0x9B, 0x86, 0x59, 0x73, 0x38, 0xAC, 0xBB };

        // Compares two byte arrays in length-constant time; from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16953231/cryptography-net-avoiding-timing-attack
        byte diff = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
            diff |= (byte)(entered[i] ^ pbkdf2[i]);
        return diff == 0;
    }
```

That said, the commenters above are correct: It's a bad security practice to hard-code a password like this.  You should give yourself the ability to change your password without having to recompile.  But, at least by using a good password hashing algorithm like PBKDF2 you do significantly reduce the risk that an attacker with access to your code could derive your password.

Comment: The required security depends on It depends on what you are protecting, from whom and the skills and motivations and the value of the key and what it protects. Define these things to determine the level of work factor you need to create the security you need.